# windows 7 restrict file access

Tags: windows, acl

If I want to restrict the access of a folder to myself only, and considering I am the owner, can I leave the Users and Everyone groups in the ACL or do I have to remove them ?

If I remove these groups, will I be able to access the folder anyway ?

I have read the access control chapter in windows help and it's not explicitely specified there.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to remove the `Everyone` and `Users` users to prevent those files being accessible by everybody.

As long as you put yourself (your username) in the ACL then you will retain access.  Make sure you do this or you may lose access.

Comment: Also, don't use "Deny" permissions, particularly with things like `Everyone` and `Users` or you'll have a hard time regaining access afterwards, since "Deny" ACEs take higher precedence than "Allow."

Comment: You are correct, and I have also found the following statements in Windows Help : 
 
"In most cases, Deny overrides Allow unless a folder is inheriting conflicting settings from different parents. In that case, the setting inherited from the parent closest to the object in the subtree will have precedence.

Inherited Deny permissions do not prevent access to an object if the object has an explicit Allow permission entry."


So the bottom line is : 
Explicit permissions have precedence over inherited ones.
Deny has precedence over Allow.

Comment: @Bluz Deny *always* takes precedence in file and folder permissions, as well as share permissions.